# Parallel execution of sh script in multiple servers

Tags: shell-script, remote-management, pdsh

I am trying to execute action in multiple servers in my loop but I would like to launch my actions in the first server and go directly to the second one without waiting for the first one to complite .

```
HOSTS="host1 host2"
    For hostname in ${HOST} ;
do ssh -tt ${USERNAME}@${hostname} << EOF
actions
exit
EOF
Done
```

Anyone has an idea hos to do that in linux sh bash ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I see that if I need to launch command in background i need to put the "&" in the and of my command. If I have multiple command I need to do it for all ? or can I do it after "EOF &"

Comment: @user236012 lmgtfy.com links [are not allowed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/15650/203101) here since they are condescending and unhelpful. On top of which, yours was completely useless since it searches for something unrelated to what the OP wants to do.

Answer (score 1):

`pdsh` would appear to meet your needs.  Runs ssh connections in parallel, in a multi threaded manner.

Example:

```
$ pdsh -w 192.168.1.4,192.168.1.250 uname -r
192.168.1.4: 2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64
192.168.1.250: 2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.x86_64
$
```

[Parallel shell with pdsh](http://www.linux-magazine.com/Issues/2014/166/Parallel-Shells)

[How can I send single file to multiple remote sites at the same time?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48237/how-can-i-send-single-file-to-multiple-remote-sites-at-the-same-time)

Comment: I don't have the pdsh in our machine.

Comment: Do you know other alternative .

Comment: Multithreaded code in Python, if you have that installed, is fairly easy to write.  You could write your own Python script which essentially does what pdsh does.

Comment: I have Python installed , but I never used it , I will try it to change a little, but I will be grateful if you can specify which command I need to use with Python or if you have an example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see there is a lot of module that we can import and use but is there any solution based on the default Python modules ?

Comment: try https://gist.github.com/boopathi/4046754 for starters

Answer (score 1):

Use GNU Parallel:

```
parallel -S host1,host2 --nonall uname -a
```

If the task is more complex, make a function:

```
do_actions() {
   action
   packed
   function
}
export -f do_actions
HOSTS="host1,host2"
parallel -S $HOSTS --ssh 'ssh -l '$USERNAME --nonall --env do_actions do_actions
```

If the username is the same as `whoami` then this is enough:

```
parallel -S $HOSTS --nonall --env do_actions do_actions
```

GNU Parallel does not have to be installed globally: If it is not install you can do a personal installation.

```
wget pi.dk/3
bash 3
```